# How to handle async tcpClient connection in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, tcpclient

I have several devices which listen on the same port. I am just sending different messages like A, B, C and get some environment values. All devices have different IPs. What I am trying to do is making an async connection to the device and send the messages in a synchronous way to the sensors.

for I/O bound async operations I mostly follow [this](https://igorpopov.io/2018/06/30/asynchronous-programming-in-csharp/)! and implemented based on what he wrote. Here what I implemented.

```
 static async Task CallingMethodAsync()
    {
        List<string> devices = new List<string>
        {
            "10.20.30.116",
            "127.0.0.1",
            "10.20.30.149",
            "10.20.30.100"
        };

        List<string> messages = new List<string>
        {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
        };
        List<Task> deviceList = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var device in devices)
        {

            foreach (var message in messages )
            {
                deviceList.Add(ConnectAsClientAsync(device, message));
            }
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(deviceList);
    }


static  Task ConnectAsClientAsync(string device,string  message)
    {
            return  new Task(  () =>
            {

                byte[] ClientRequestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    try
                    {
                        using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient(device, 11000))
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Connected ->>" + device + " from port:" + port);


                            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                            {
                                networkStream.Write(ClientRequestBytes, 0, ClientRequestBytes.Length);
                                byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                                var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
                                   Console.WriteLine("response ->>" + response+ " from device:"+device);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SocketException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No Answer!! from ->>" + device + " from port:" + port);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not Connected ->>" + device + " from port:" + port);
                    }
            });
    }
```

I am not getting ant response even I cannot connect to the devices even though they are listening. It just stuck and do not print anything. I don't know what the problem is.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing `new Task` with `Task.Run`

Comment: @KevinGosse thank you very much for your reply. The link I provided you within the post says never call Task.Run() in I/O bound async calls, just start a new Task and Task.Whenall after populating the list. That's the point which is confusing to me. When I change it with Task.Run it works however, I am still not sure if it is good to do it in an I/O bound operation.  Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: `The link I provided you within the post says never call Task.Run() in I/O bound async calls` In your code you're not actually using any async API, only synchronous I/O, that's why you need Task.Run to execute your code in parallel. If you rewrite your code to use TcpClient.ConnectAsync and Stream.ReadAsync, you'll see that your method will naturally return a task (the one created by the async/await machinery). Then you have no need of Task.Run, and it'll work like you expected

Comment: The reason it didn't work is that `new Task` returns an non-started task. This is a very advanced use-case (in fact I'm not even sure there is any legitimate use left nowadays). The ways you are expected to create a task are either using a TaskCompletionSource, using async/await, or using Task.Run. You should take some time to play with each of those APIs to understand how they work

Comment: @KevinGosse thank you very much for valuable info. I modified my code, on the server side,if I can see the message sent. what I did is    
return  new Task(  async () =>
                {
using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
{ await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(device, 11000);
 using (var networkStream =  tcpClient.GetStream())
{
networkStream.WriteAsync(ClientRequestBytes, 0, ClientRequestBytes.Length);
}
}
}
This still does not show anything on the server side. Why I am insisting on async connection to device is beacuse since all have different IPs I can do it and make my app faster.